# Error de instalación de visual studio 2022 en windows 11

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, visual

Les comento que al intentar instalar Visual Studio Community 2022 en windows11, me aparece casi a inicios de instalación, el siguiente error:

[image: No se descargó ningún archivo de instalación.]

Después di clic en continuar para instalar por completo, pero me generó más poblemas. También intenté con dar clic en Reintentar, pero el problema es el mismo. Luego lo desintalé de raiz por completo e intenté instalar de nuevo y todavía tengo el mismo error.

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo solucionar este problema de error: No se descargó ningún achivo de instalación.

Comment: Intenta descargar el "ISO offline": https://fredyfx.com/post/instalar-visual-studio-2017-iso-offline

Comment: @fredyfx agradezco mucho que haya contestado a mi pregunta.
Me dirigí a la página que me compartió, en esta veo que habla acerca de la instalación Visual Studio 2017 ISO

Comment: también menciona que este no existe y que hay una manera de tener el instalador offline. Entonces me fui a la dirección que ofrece dicha página que me compartió, para descargar nuevamente el instalador de Visual Community 2022
con nombre vs_Community.

Comment: Estaba tratando de seguir los pasos para la instalación offline, que sinceramente no conozco de este tema, el caso es que cuando ejecuté esta línea "vs_community.exe --layout c:\vs2022offline" desde el símbbolo del sistema me generó error.
En cuanto a la carpeta que cree en la raiz de mi disco duro fue vs2022offline. Entonces, discúlpeme por no comprender nada de esto, pero me podría indicar por qué me genera este error por favor.

Comment: normal, no pasa nada, vamos solucionando el tema, aquí están las instrucciones en español de la misma web de Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022 El problema que hay, probablemente sea por conexión inestable a internet. Saludos.